# How i get third Column values from $scope.item

Tags: angularjs

How i get third Column values from `$scope.item` based on select

```
$scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30, xxx: '15' },{ name: 'two', age: 27,xxx: '12' },{ name: 'three', age: 50,xxx: '16' }];


<p>selected item is : {{selectedItem.xxx}}</p>

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectAction()">
   <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.age}}">{{item.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access third element using index

```
 <p>selected item is : {{items[2].xxx}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `selectedItem` as the model of the dropdown, and the value of each `option` is set to `item.age`. So, for current selection, `$scope.selectedItem` will represent `age` instead of `xxx`.

If you want to select `xxx` instead, change the value of the `option` to `xxx`:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.xxx}}">{{item.name}}</option>
```

Now when you select an option in the dropdown, `$scope.selectedItem` will represent the value of `xxx` in the corresponding item.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would be to use ng-value to assign the whole item object as the value.

```
<p>selected item is : {{selectedItem.xxx}}</p>

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectAction()">
  <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-value="{{item}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

example in action here: https://plnkr.co/edit/e7j8jkVrVNAo3Ar9sc2q?p=preview